# Can i change the location where netbeans stores project groups

Tags: dropbox, netbeans-8

I work on three different computers. However, I store my sources in dropbox, thus I have access from all computers to the same sources. I need to access the same project group from those computers. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can store all of your NetBeans settings in DropBox (including the project group). Start NetBeans with the `--userdir` argument like this:

```
netbeans.exe --userdir C:\MyOtherUserdir
```

You may want to copy your current user directory to your DropBox folder first so that you don't have to reconfigure all of your NetBeans settings and recreate the project group.

See http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqAlternateUserdir for more information.